# Can I speed up my hard drive at all?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, speed

Here are my specs. General Information :

```
 SMART : Version 1.1 
Information Hard Disk # Manufacturer : Seagate   
Model : ST750LM022 HN-M7 Serial Number : S2SUJ9BC Revision (Firmware) : 2A Serial ATA : Yes 

Serial ATA Version : 2.0 Support : ACS-2   
Size : 750GB   
Solid State Disk (SSD) : Format : 2.5"   
Speed : 5400 rpm   
Cache : 8 192 KB   
ECC Size : 4   
Multiple Sector : 16   
IORDY : Yes   
LBA Mode : Yes   
DMA Mode : Yes   
NCQ Mode : Yes   
SCT Mode : Yes   
DCO Mode : Yes  
TRIM Mode : No   
GPL Mode : Yes   
WWW 64-bit : Yes   
HPA Mode : No   
Sanitize Mode : No   
TCQ Mode : No   
CFA Mode : No   
CFA Power Mode : No   
NV Cache Power Mode   
Volatile Write Cache   
SETMAX : No   
Multiword DMA Mode :   
PIO Mode : PIO 4   
UDMA Mode max. : 6 (   
UDMA Mode Enabled :   
Transport : Serial A   
SMART : Yes - En   
SMART Self-Test : Ye   
AAM : No   
Write Cache : Yes   
NV Cache Enabled : N   
Streaming Mode : No   
APM Mode : Yes - Disabled PUIS Mode : No   
Security Mode : No   
Trusted Computing : No   
48-bit Address : Yes   

Cylinders : 1453521   
Heads : 16  
Sectors per Track : 63   

SMART Information Disk ST750 Health : 98% (estimated)   
Performance : 93% (estimated) Reallocated Sectors : 0   
Pending Sectors : 0   
Uncorrectable Sectors : 0   
Total Boot : 476 x   
PowerOn Count : 846 hours   
Failure Prediction Supported Threshold Exceeding : No   

Raw Read Error Rate (01) : 00 Throughput Performance (02) : Spin Up Time (03) : 00D88 (Th Start/Stop Count (04) : 001E0 Reallocated Sector Count (05) Seek Error Rate (07) : 00000
 Seek Time Performance (08) :
 Power On Hours Count (09) : 0 Spin Retry Count (0A) : 00000 Calibration Retry Count (0B) Power Cycle Count (0C) (0B) (B5) : 815DE (Threshol (0B) (B7) : 00000 (Threshol (0B) (B8) : 00000 (Threshol (0B) (BA) : 00000 (Threshol (0B) (BB) : 00000 (Threshol (0B) (BC) : 00000 (Threshol (0B) Airflow (BE) : 20025 (T (0B) (BF) : 000A7 (Threshol (0B) Power-Off Retract Count (0B) Load/Unload Cycle Count (0B) Temperature (C2) : 2002 (0B) Hardware ECC Recovered (0B) Reallocation Event Coun (0B) Current Pending Sector (0B) Off-Line Uncorrectable (0B) Ultra ATA CRC Error Rat (0B)

Partitions : 
Hard Disk #1 : Partitio (0B)  
Monitoring Information (0B) ST750LM0 22 HN-M750MBB (0B)

Advices : 
The symbol indicate : Approxim The symbol indicate : Informat
```

Its on my laptop so i'd prefer not to have to replace the drive, is there anything i can do to speed things up?

Thanks so much!

Comment: A SSD does not have a RPM value.  Where did you get this information from?  I cannot answer this question until the source of this information is known.

Comment: @Ramhound it's not an SSD, it's [a HDD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822152290), as stated in the post.

Comment: @Huskehn - Explain this: **Solid State Disk (SSD) : Format : 2.5"** the user never actually said it was a HDD.  I have an answer saved once I understand where this log file came from.  **Besides I already knew it was a HDD I was going from the log file**

Comment: You can defrag, but unless things are seriously fragmented it is only going to be a small boost.  A 240/256GB or 480/512gb SSD will make your laptop scream way faster than any tweaks.

Comment: Question is too vague to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't speedup the Samsung SpinPoint ST750LM022 750GB. This is a slow 5400rpm HDD. If your laptop supports mSATA, buy a mSATA SSD and install Windows on it and use the HDD as storage drive for data.